# Preserving Pandas dataframe dtype while running astype

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to preserve dataframe dtypes while executing `astype`? I have a dataframe that has a bunch of empty lists in across a variety of fields and so I'm using the following to cast every single column into a string and then replace the lists:

```
data_normalized = data_normalized.astype(str).replace('[]', '', regex=False)
```

However, since this is casting every single column into a string, it's also converting float64 and integer fields into string. I'd like to preserve those dtypes because running `infer_objects` doesn't work:

```
data_normalized = data_normalized.infer_objects()
```

If I look at the dtypes of `data_normalized`, they're all `object`. Any way to keep the non-object dtypes without explicitly naming the columns?

Comment: Are you looking for [`select_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)?

Comment: Why do you have a DataFrame with lists in the first place? You can generally save yourself a ton of trouble if you fix that part of the problem before applying this bandaid fix later.

Answer (score 1):

Empty lists are length 0 and since you want to replace with the empty string anyway we don't need to worry about those.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[[], 1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6, 8.6], 
                 'c': ['foo', [], [], 'bar']})

for col in df:
    try:
        df.loc[df[col].str.len().eq(0), col] = ''
    except AttributeError:
        continue

print(df)
#   a    b    c
#0     4.0  foo
#1  1  5.0     
#2  2  6.0     
#3  3  8.6  bar

print(df.dtypes)
#a     object
#b    float64     # Remained Float
#c     object
#dtype: object

df['a'].to_numpy()
#array(['', 1, 2, 3], dtype=object)  # individual values remain `Int`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether it is empty list and then only convert:

```
data_normalized.apply(lambda y: ['' if x=='[]' else x for x in y])
```

Although the datatype of the columns will be Object, but when you access individual values it will be the same as original.